# Electric Power Transferred on a Load

Tags: power

I got this problem:
A transmission system is composed by an amplifier and the antenna. The transmit amplifier has an available power of 2mW and a resistive impedance of 10Ω. The antenna (in series with the amplifier) has input impedance given by a series of a resistance R=10 and an inductance L=31.8nH. Evaluate the power on the antenna assuming the impedance content over the bandwidth of the signal. Signal has f=100Mhz

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fMVPVw.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This is the schematic. The signal input is a QPSK modulated signal.

Now, in this case, we are not in the maximum transfer of the power on the load because, clearly, the impedances are different.
The exercise says the answer is 1mW but, if I apply the formula \$P_{L}=P_{in}\tfrac{\left | Z_{L} \right |^{2}}{\left | Z_{L}+Z_{in} \right |^{2}}\$ the result is different.

How should I proceed?

Comment: Are you trying to calculate complex power or real power? Can you show your work?

Comment: I know that \$ Z_{L1}=j2πfL=j20 \$ , \$ Z_{L}=R_{2}+Z_{L1} \$ and \$ R_{1}=Z_{1} \$ and then I've used them in the above formula with \$ P_{in}=2mW \$

Comment: Show all of your work. You haven't even told us what result you calculate, just that it is "different".

Comment: \$Z_{L}=R2+Z_{L1}=10+20j Ω\$ , \$Z_{in}=10 Ω\$ \$P_{in}=2mW\$ so \$P_{L}=P_{in}\tfrac{\left | Z_{L} \right |^{2}}{\left | Z_{L}+Z_{in} \right |^{2}}=2*10^{-3}\tfrac{\left | 10+20j \right |^{2}}{\left | 20+20j \right |^{2}}=2*10^{-3}\tfrac{(\sqrt{10^{2}+20^{2}} )^{2}}{( \sqrt{20^{2}+20^{2}})^{2}}=2*10^{-3}\tfrac{10^{2}+20^{2}}{20^{2}+20^{2}}=2*10^{-3}\tfrac{500}{800}=1.25mW\$ that is not 1mW as described in the solutions